# Rendering a specific stylesheet for a view or set of views

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Inside of my views directory I have two folders with files inside. Those folders are titled `main` and `off-brand-main`. I have similar but differing CSS files that need to be used with each, respectively. Those CSS are titled `main.css` and `off-brand-main.css`.

I'm stumped as to how to call the respective stylesheets, and where to make the calls. Should I do it in the controller in `def new`?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the  section of your template file (often 'application.html.erb'), you can use a conditional to set the stylesheets to use based on something...

```
<Head>
  <% if ... %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "main" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "off-brand-main" %>
```

The conditional could be a controller (controller_name == 'something') and/or action (action_name == 'something').